Access Call Audio Streams for a Call Translation Application on Android?
I have been assigned to develop an Android application for real-time call translation. The application requires access to the audio streams of phone calls (both incoming and outgoing) to process and translate the conversation in real time.
I understand that Android imposes restrictions on call recording, especially in versions 9 and later, to ensure user privacy. However, this functionality is critical for the app's purpose.
requirements of app:
Capture both sides of the call audio (caller and receiver).
Process the audio in real time or near real-time for translation.
Ensure compliance with Android's privacy and security guidelines.
I explored the following approaches:
Using MediaRecorder and AudioRecord, but these do not seem to work with call audio due to Android's restrictions.
Is there any way to access call audio streams on Android (especially in Android 9 and above) while adhering to platform guidelines?
